# Error for style.css in angular application

Tags: css, angular

I'm working on an application using angular 7. The application throws this error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

What I tried and didn't work is setting it in `angular.json` inside the `style` tag, didn't work. Now i have this but it still not working:

Here's my index.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NTT Hotline Manager</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

My `style.css` file:

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import "../src/app/css/all.css";
```

I have imported the `css` from my `all.css` file

My folder structure:

```
myProject
`-- Webcontent
    `-- src
        |-- app
        |   |-- components
        |   `-- css
        |       `-- all.css
        `-- styles.css
```

But for some reason it's not working and throws the error above. What can be the problem?

Comment: Your file is named `style.css` while the linked one is `styles.css`, the `s` might be the problem. also sometimes removing the `type` attr. works, for me at least.

Comment: Oops sorry my bad, its good in my code just missed the 's' here, edited the question

Comment: Are you using webpack? I wonder you may need to double check the root directory, the path for your file loader or whatever config you are using for your CSS loader.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are adding the all.css file in a wrong path and is not finding all.css. Try to change the path to `@import "./app/css/all.css";` and remove from index.html `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href: '../Webcontent/src/styles.css'>`. In your angular.json you must have this structure too.

```
"styles": [
   "Webcontent/src/styles.scss"
],
```

Comment: The problem is because it doesn't find the css's so if you could add an image of your folders it would be helpfull.

Comment: added my folder structure

Comment: can't find the file with ```../``` , finds it with ```./``` but same error :/

Comment: ok, then I think you have the problem in the angular.json. Try the new solution that I have edited.

Comment: should be good but now i get a different error : Module error Emitted value instead of an instance of Error CssSyntaxError I will search this